# Unexpected newline (catcode magic)

Tags: macros, line-breaking, boxes

I am playing with Tex catcodes and hboxes. The following code should produce three lines of output:

```
A...1...
B...2...
C...3...
```

However, for some reason it makes a line break between `A` and `...1...`, and I have no idea why.

Here is the code:

```
\def\changeCatcodes{
    \catcode`A=13
    \catcode`B=13
    \catcode`C=13
}

\begingroup
\changeCatcodes
\gdefA{\argtohbox{\string A}}
\gdefB{\argtohbox{\string B}}
\gdefC{\argtohbox{\string C}}
\endgroup

\gdef\argtohbox#1{\hbox to 20pt{#1}}

\gdef\newstring{\penalty-10000}

\catcode`\^^M=13 % one for reading macro definition
\def\specialenv{%
    \begingroup%
    \parindent0pt%
    \catcode`\^^M=13 % ... and one for actually changing it when it is executed
    \changeCatcodes%
    \let^^M\newstring%
}
\catcode`\^^M=5 % return catcode back

\def\endspecialenv{\endgroup}

\specialenv
A...1...
B...2...
C...3...
\endspecialenv
\end
```

Comment: the \hbox{A} doesn't change to hmode, this only happens at the first period.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simpler version is

[image]

from

```
\hbox{A}1
\hbox{B}2
\hbox{C}3

\bye
```

as you have no `\leavevmode` before the `\hbox` the first hbox stays in vertical mode, but then the paragraph is started (in your case by `...`) so the following hboxes are found in hmode.

Answer (score 4):

When TeX is in vertical mode, it stacks boxes (possibly adding interline glue) between them and adds other vertical material that comes along.

If you contribute `\hbox{...}` when TeX is in vertical mode, it just obeys its nature and stacks it along with the material already contributed.

Some tokens cause vertical mode to be set aside and horizontal mode to start. The purpose of horizontal mode is to prepare one or more boxes to be contributed upon returning to vertical mode (this is triggered by `\par`, which might be added implicitly). Among these tokens there is *not* `\hbox`, as noted above. However, if `\hbox` is found when in horizontal mode, it is contributed in this mode.

A character, in your case the first period, causes horizontal mode to start. it will end after `\endspecialenv` or, more precisely, by `\end` that implicitly supplies `\par`.

You get the same output from

```
\parindent=0pt

\hbox to 20pt{A}...1...\break
\hbox to 20pt{B}...2...\break
\hbox to 20pt{C}...3...\break
\end
```

[image]

together with several `Underfull \hbox` messages:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 3
\tenrm A

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 4
\tenrm B

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) detected at line 5
\tenrm C

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--6
[]\tenrm ...1...

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--6
[]\tenrm ...2...

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--6
[]\tenrm ...3...

Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 3--6
```

Fixed code:

```
\def\changeCatcodes{
    \catcode`A=13
    \catcode`B=13
    \catcode`C=13
}

\begingroup
\changeCatcodes
\gdef A{\argtohbox{\string A}}
\gdef B{\argtohbox{\string B}}
\gdef C{\argtohbox{\string C}}
\endgroup

\def\argtohbox#1{\hbox to 20pt{#1\hss}}

\def\newstring{\hfil\penalty-10000 }

\catcode`\^^M=13 % one for reading macro definition
\def\specialenv{%
    \begingroup%
    \parindent0pt%
    \catcode`\^^M=13 % ... and one for actually changing it when it is executed
    \changeCatcodes%
    \let^^M\newstring%
    \leavevmode%
}
\catcode`\^^M=5 % return catcode back

\def\endspecialenv{\unpenalty\endgroup}

\specialenv
A...1...
B...2...
C...3...
\endspecialenv
\end
```

1. `\hss` contributes stretchable glue that avoids the box being underfull
2. `\hfil` before `\penalty-10000` avoids the line being underfull
3. `\leavevmode` starts horizontal mode
4. `\unpenalty` at the end removes the penalty at the end of the last line
5. note the space after `-10000` that avoids possible untimely expansion of the following token

You might enjoy studying this different way to define your active characters:

```
\def\activedef#1{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`#1\lowercase{\endgroup\def~}%
}
\activedef A{\argtohbox{A}}
\activedef B{\argtohbox{B}}
\activedef C{\argtohbox{C}}
```

These definitions need not to be `\global` nor it is necessary to open a group and to issue `\changeCatcodes`. And no `\string` either.